# Overflow of a table hidden?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, overflow

What I'm trying to do here is create a table with Javascript (success) in a div with a **max width of 300px**.

Now if my table is wider than 300px I want the **overflow to be hidden**, but what happens is the table scales its width down to 300px each time even though I am setting the `<td>` to be a different width:

```
<style>
#tablespace {
margin:auto;
position:relative;
width:300px;
overflow:hidden;    
}
</style>

<button onclick="CreateTable()" >Try it</button>
<div id="tablespace">
   <p id="tablespace"> </p>
</div>

<script>
function CreateTable()
{
    var tablecontents = "";
    tablecontents = "<table border=1>";
//number of rows
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
{ 
tablecontents += "<tr>";
//number of columns
    for (var a = 0; a < 5; a ++)
    {
      tablecontents += "<td height= 50, width= 100>" + i + "</td>";      
    }
    tablecontents += "</tr>";
}
tablecontents += "</table>";
document.getElementById("tablespace").innerHTML = tablecontents;
}
</script>
```

So where I have used height of a cell as 50px and width of 100px because my max width of the div is 300px, I should only see 2 and a half cells then the rest is hidden but this is not the case.

I understand it is probably a basic mistake but I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-width` on table cells.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/jUqvj/

Quick Example:

CSS:

```
div {
    max-width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#table1 td {
    min-width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #0ff;
}
#table2 td {
    width: 100px; /* here it's not effective as desired */
    border: 1px solid #0ff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<pre>With min-width on table cells</pre>
<div>
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <td>Col1</td>
            <td>Col2</td>
            <td>Col3</td>
            <td>Col4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col1</td>
            <td>Col2</td>
            <td>Col3</td>
            <td>Col4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col1</td>
            <td>Col2</td>
            <td>Col3</td>
            <td>Col4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<hr><br>
<pre>Without min-width on table cells</pre>
<div>
    <table id="table2">
        <tr>
            <td>Col1</td>
            <td>Col2</td>
            <td>Col3</td>
            <td>Col4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col1</td>
            <td>Col2</td>
            <td>Col3</td>
            <td>Col4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col1</td>
            <td>Col2</td>
            <td>Col3</td>
            <td>Col4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change this (I don't know whether this is actually already in the code):

```
tablecontents += "<td height= 50, width= 100>" + i + "</td>";
```

to

```
tablecontents += '<td height="50px", width="100px">' + i + "</td>";
```

BTW I would recommend to skip all thes HTML3 parameters and do it all by seperate CSS class like

```
tablecontents += '<td class='croppedTable'>' + i + "</td>";
```

and

```
<style>
#tablespace {
margin:auto;
position:relative;
width:300px;
overflow:hidden;    
}

.croppedTable {
... some styles ...
}
.croppedTable TD {
... some additional styles ...
width: 100px;
height: 50px;

}
</style>
```